# Access guest from virsh

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm, virsh

I am running Centos 7 x86-64. I installed a guest (again Centos 7) through kickstart as an exercise. I prepared my kickstart file, I validated it and I launched with virt-install.

If something went wrong with the network configuration (During install I got no problem, I created a local repo on Host FTP server as source for the install) how can I connect to the machine?

Only SSH or virsh foresee some other connection method?

How can I find my machine running network configuration from outside?

I am running a barebone Centos7 installation so only command line, no graphical interface at all.

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh to your physical host from another one having graphical interface with X forwarding enabled (`ssh -X machinename`), and look at the the VM with virt-manager

You will need X running on the machine you're connecting from. For Mac OS it's XQuartz